# Using ResourceManager and CultureInfo on a Multilanguage App

Tags: c#, vb.net

EDIT: Solved by changing "Student Assistant.Lang.langres" to "Student_Assistant.Lang.langres"

I know there's plenty of tutorials about this, but I've gone through many, and I keep getting the same error: "MissingManifestException" with the description 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.'

The resource manager load:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Student Assistant");
resManager = new ResourceManager("Student Assistant.Lang.langres", a);
switchLanguage();
//Loads all text
LoadTexts();
```

Switch language:  Changes the language depending on what's selected.

```
private void switchLanguage() {
        if (spanishToolStripMenuItem.Checked) {
            culInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        } else {
            culInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        }
}
```

Load Texts: Simply loads texts, used to check if strings are loaded.

```
private void LoadTexts() {
    this.calendar.Text = resManager.GetString("tabcalendar");
}
```

As seen in the image, the error occurs in line 91, and when checking the resManager, the ResourceSets property from it appears with Count=0.

Here's an extra picture of the solution explorer, as it might be useful:
[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFJe0.png).

One last thing worth mentioning is that this is inside a Google Drive Folder, but I doubt that's has anything to do.

Comment: code. code is useful. not images.

Comment: Sorry, changed it into code.